Struggling Marigolds After Transplanting
I started African Marigolds and White Marigolds indoors. They had strong, tall, thick stems with lots of leaves. Recently transplanted them outdoors in large raised bed. They are lying down, weak, still green. Help! I don’t know if I watered too much or not enough. Thank you for any suggestions!

Hi @Sherri, welcome to the site.  Did you harden the marigolds off in between their indoor life and outdoor life?  What general part of the world are you in?

Have you looked at night or in early morning for signs of slug/snail attack? Either the actual animals or their glistening slime trails?
